# Free trial length changing in iOS subscription package

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, subscription, trial

We use auto-renewable subscriptions in our application and we set free trials as an introductory offer. But we haven't experienced what if the trial length changes yet.

If we change the free trial length of an existing subscription package, are the existing users notified via e-mail or notifications?

For example we are applying 7-days free trial for our subscription now, what if we change this period with 3-days? Will the subscribers in the trial period (let's say he is on the 5th day of free trial) be notified? In other words, will the existing subscribers in trial period continue with 7 days and new subscribers start with 3 days to trial period?

Is there anyone who has experienced this before?
Thanks for all replies in advance.

Answer (score 2):

AppStore generate a receipt for every IAP separately so, subscription start date and end date are there. If someone registered for 7 days and 3 days has passed. when you changed trial period to 3 days it does not affect the previous trial period. They still use 7 day trial until the "their" trial period end.